# Delete item from dictionary and Listbox

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox

I have a program that puts the contents of a dictionary in a Tkinter `Listbox`, but I'm having trouble deleting it from the `Listbox` and the dictionary.

```
from tkinter import *
import ast

f = open("orders.txt", "r")
contents = f.read()
f.close()
things = ast.literal_eval(contents)
secondthing = [things, "test"]
root = Tk()
f = Frame(root).pack()
l = Listbox(root)
b = Button(root, text = "delete selection", command = lambda: delete(l))
b.pack()
l.pack()

for i, j in things.items():
    oneitem = i + " " + j
    l.insert(END, oneitem)

def delete(listbox):

    global things
    # Delete from Listbox
    selection = l.curselection()
    l.delete(selection[0])
    # Delete from list that provided it
    evaluater = l.get(selection[0])
    value = eval(evaluater)
    ind = things.index(value)
    del(things[ind])
    print(things)

root.mainloop()
```

When I try to delete something it gives me:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/Users/mimmo/black_market/aaa.py", line 12, in <lambda>
    b = Button(root, text = "delete selection", command = lambda: delete(l))
  File "/Users/mimmo/black_market/aaa.py", line 28, in delete
    value = eval(evaluater)
  File "<string>", line 1
    ohhh ohhhhh
         ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

Can someone help me because I can delete it from the `Listbox`, I just have an error when deleting it from the dictionary.

The contents of `orders.txt`:

```
{"ayyy" : "ayyyyyy", "ohhh" : "ohhhhh"}
```

Comment: You need to [edit] your question and provide sample contents of the `orders.txt` file that will reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I would recommend using `json` or `pickle` to store contents of the dictionary - it's the most common practice. I don't really understand what do you want to do so I wrote a function which deletes an element from listbox and things by it's index.
An error you are getting is caused by `eval` function which tries to intepret your listbox item as python code. Of course, it's getting syntax error.

```py
# Deletes element from listbox and thigs by it's index
def delete(listbox, index: int):
    global things
    item = listbox.get(index)
    key = item.split()[0]
    del things[key]
    listbox.delete(index)
```

Comment: thank you, this worked, i will also look into json and pickle i just used dictionarys because its what i know how to use!